# How can i retrive website URL from Joomla DB

Tags: database, joomla

i'm managing lot of websites, few of those are Joomla.
Last webmaster has gone without giving any help and i've those Joomla DB that i cannot understand which websites are related to.
I mean, on wordpress, i'd see on "option" table to check URL but where i can find this information on Joomla?
Thanks

Comment: Actually not solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, no chances.
Only solution i see is to backup and delete DBs one by one, if more than one, and see which website has gone "offline"

Answer (score 1):

Have a look in the configuration.php of each site instead. In them, you can see which database is connected to the specific site.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i just can see DBs. We have multiple providers, and i can't check them all becouse some credentials have been changed by clients. I've about 10 joomla DB that i actually can't understand which website are related to, after that i could reach FTP and check configuration.php but i actually can't find this information. The point is, i should empty this big DB which has >100 CMS installations on it, every DB marked by prefix. It's a kind of mess as you can imagine, created years ago to keep prices cheap.

Answer (score 0):

Joomla by itself does not store the web site URL in this tables or configuration files, and I take that as a merit over Wordpress. The advantage of not storing the URL is that I could simply change web server's configuration when I want to change a site's URL. Everything will appear perfectly, unless for some reason a programmer chose to hard-code the web site URL into his code (which is a very bad practice).

So I suggest look into web server's configuration to get your the document roots and then relate the configuration.php file in there to the databases.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, as i said before i can't check configuration.php as i really wanted too